# Batched area of triangle calculation

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape (N, 3, 3) where N is the number of triangles. Is there a way to calculate the area of a triangle from a 3x3 matrix of coordinates so I can batch along the N dimension?

Most methods for vectorizing area computations rely on subtracting one of the vertices from the other two and taking the cross product which I don't think is possible to do with batching.

Comment: did you read `np.cross` docs?

Comment: Yes, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: *"... subtracting one of the vertices from the other two and taking the cross product which I don't think is possible to do with batching."*  Why wouldn't that be possible?  You can slice and subtract torch tensors, and you can use `torch.cross` and `torch.norm`.  If you've tried it, show your code and explain where it didn't work or where you got stuck.

Comment: Each row in the 3*3 matrix represents a 3D vertex, right? But this is a volume, not an area.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Area of Triangle and equation of a plane on which triangle lies on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71346322/numpy-area-of-triangle-and-equation-of-a-plane-on-which-triangle-lies-on)